# Can I export the contents of Google Chrome's DOM inspector?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to be able to expand all nodes in Chrome's DOM inspector and get the result in my text editor. How can I do this?

The closest to this I can manage is to view page source, but that shows the original DOM, omitting the modifications made to it via javascript.s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you click on a node and press Ctrl+C, you get that node (and all child nodes recursively) copied to the clipboard.

To get everything, simply use this feature on the top-most node (the `<html>` element. This nodes encompasses nearly everything, the only thing this misses is the `<!DOCTYPE>` element, which you can copy separately.